# Why is the case of branch names wrong when using the 'git status' command?

Tags: git, macos

I created a branch 'SoftPhoneWidget' (with a capital P) via terminal command `git branch SoftPhoneWidget`. When I use the command `git status` it lists the branch I am on as 'SoftphoneWidget' (with a lowercase p). However, if I list all branches with `git branch -r`, it does show the branch as the correct (capital P) 'SoftPhoneWidget':

[image: text]

The `.git/refs/heads/` folder shows the file name as 'SoftPhoneWidget' (capital P):

[image]

I am using 2019 Mac Terminal (screenshots are of vs code because it's easier to see), git cli, and BitBucket.

What could be the cause of this random casing error?

It's not terribly important but after a long day a weird bug like this can cause some extra time and frustration when the `git status` command shows something different than what is needed to push to that branch.

Comment: It could be a typo. Did you check the command history?

Comment: generally, macs use a case insensitive file system.  That choice has cost the world hundreds of thousands of hours (years) in debugging time, and is probably the source of this issue.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes, the screenshot you're seeing is from me arrowing up to the original command text

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Linux use a case sensitive file system. That choice has cost the world hundreds of thousands of yours yearly in debugging time :o).

Answer (score 0):

As @William Pursell mentioned in a comment, this is a danger of using git with OS X and Windows filesystems (which are case agnostic). The article [Git is case-sensitive and your filesystem may not be - Weird folder merging on Windows](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/git-is-casesensitive-and-your-filesystem-may-not-be-weird-folder-merging-on-windows) explains some of the problems that can occur due to this and some techniques to repair.

The most likely cause was a checkout using the incorrect case, which your filesystem happily satisfied, but that git sees as distinct due to case sensitivity.

You could set `git config --global core.ignorecase false` which might help catch this issue for you in the future.